# Change glue jobs to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I got my first job as a BI support with AWS and the company has several glue jobs which is a very expensive game so I want to try and change it, instead of using glue jobs to use lambda function. The question is, how do I change a glue job to a lambda function? can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general: **you don't**.

A glue Job can a) run for faaaar longer and b) can consume faaaar more resources and c) can have code and dependencies far exceeding the limits of Lambda. You can't replace a glue job with a lambda unless you did not need a glue job in the first place because you operate on few resources, for a short time with little code. If that is the case you would need to be a lot more specific *how* the current job is integrated. E.g. triggers will no longer work, network connectivity might no longer work, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much luk2302. Sorry that my question was very confused.. We have jobs in Glue which they're triggered by step functions any time I assume on demand, so can I not use step function but use lambda functions instead?

Comment: @WeversonGoncalvesMuciarone only if *"you did not need a glue job in the first place because you operate on few resources, for a short time with little code"*.